# Google shows my tumblr blog with original URL instead of custom domain

Tags: domains, google-search, tumblr

I'm new to domains and related stuff, I recently bought a custom domain for my tumblr blog, however when I google it, the original tumblr address shows up (jonathanwiesel.tumblr.com) not my custom domain (jonathanwiesel.com) any recommendations please?

Comment: How long ago did you add your custom domain?

Comment: Since last monday

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I googled jonathan wiesel blog and i found that your tumblr site was listed first and after that two links to your custom domain where listed.

The reason for tumblr blog appearing instead of the custom domain is that google may thinks that the both address as different and lists the site with higher ranking.

It may take some two - three weeks for your custom domain to rank higher than the tumblr domain.